# PLSQL nested loop to output data

Tags: loops, plsql, nested, dbms-output

I am trying to find a code that creates a box such as...
XXX
XXX
XXX
(exp. 3x3) depending on what the user inputs as row and height variables.  My nested loop is not working correctly.  Can I please get some help?

Heres code...

```
Set ServerOutput on;
Declare

  RectangleHeight Number(2):=5;
  RectangleWidth Number(2):=;
  RowCount Number(1) :=0;
  ColumnCount Number(1) :=0;
 Begin 
Loop 
Exit When RowCount>=RectangleHeight;
    Loop
    Exit When ColumnCount>=RectangleWidth;
    dbms_output.put_line('X');  
    ColumnCount := ColumnCount+1;
    End Loop;
RowCount := RowCount+1;
End Loop;


End;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothings really wrong with the loop as much as the logic needs tweaked a bit.
First thing you have a syntax error on line 5: `RectangleWidth Number(2):=;`
Fixing that we have a few more problems to figure out.

1) You are putting a new line `\n` after each `X` in the width portion of the loop. This should probably be a single `X` without the new line.
2) After you output the object width, what happens to the `ColumnCount` variable?
3) After you output an entire row, how do you get to a new line?

Example code with comments:

```
SET ServerOutput ON;
DECLARE
  RectangleHeight NUMBER(2) :=5;
  RectangleWidth  NUMBER(2) :=9; -- FIXED SYNTAX ERROR
  RowCount        NUMBER(1) :=0;
  ColumnCount     NUMBER(1) :=0;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN RowCount>=RectangleHeight;
    LOOP
      EXIT WHEN ColumnCount>=RectangleWidth;
        dbms_output.put('X'); -- DON'T PUT A NEW LINE, JUST USE PUT
        ColumnCount := ColumnCount+1;
    END LOOP;
    ColumnCount := 0; -- AFTER A SUCCESSFUL ROW IS OUTPUT, WE RESET OUR COLUMN COUNTER
    RowCount := RowCount+1;
    dbms_output.put_line(null); -- JUST OUTPUTTING A BLANK LINE
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

And the output using `5` and `9` as inputs for height and width respectively:

```
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
```

I feel like this is homework but I always liked these kind of visual problems.

Comment: Yep this is for homework and it does exactly what I want it to do.  Thank you very much!!!